# Can I speed up the wait time between username changes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I set my Minecraft username to a name I don't like. I don't want to wait the full 30 days to change it back or to something different. So is there ANY way I can speed up the 30 day wait?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but something tells me that this is a bit off topic.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong No, the question is Minecraft related, and Minecraft questions are (with few exceptions) on-topic. It might not be about the game itself, but it is still a question that relates to gaming, if that makes sense.

Comment: @MageXy Gotcha, I wasn't sure because some question that is similar got flagged as off topic so I was just wondering. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

As per the [official help topic](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames), you can change your username once ever 30 days. Your original username is kept on hold for 37 days, which means you have one extra week to change back if you made a mistake when you first changed it. However, you *must* wait 30 days between name changes. This cannot be avoided or sped up.

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned before, you can only change your username once every 30 days. Other people can not change it to your old nickname until 37 days after your change. [Here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames) is the article

If you would like to change your username temporarily before the 30 days you have several options:

- You can use [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2233908-forge-jarmod-ingame-username-changer-now-with) mod if you want to change it client side (singleplayer)

***Good luck!***

Comment: Please do not include links to hacked clients/servers. We don't want to encourage piracy.

Comment: @MageXy If I did something like "these options are not encouraged" but... and not include the links. I understand your point, I just finished reading the stuff at help center.

Comment: I don't think it's good to mention hacked clients at all. At best, it provides a search topic for people who want to pirate. Even "legitimate" hacked clients are avenues for spyware and viruses. I think it's best to avoid them.

Comment: @MageXy I know, I have personally worked with them for various reasons and they are not good to use. I'm just going to edit the answer so that it actually adds something.

Comment: If you know its a hacked client, and you know they're not good to use...why is it in your answer?